# How to display counter

Tags: 2013, 2010, jquery, css, tasks

Is there a way to use jQuery and Css to pop up notification to user's breadcrumb area for user's open Tasks. I can drop a web part which gets all the pending tasks for browser's user. I see following link but I have no idea how to do it with sharepoint. any help will be appreciated. Just like Facebook does, it displays a number top of the mailbox or notification, etc.

http://codepen.io/BaylorRae/pen/eCFId

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is less a "SharePoint thing" and more a "JavaScript thing". If you have the counts, you can poke them into the DOM wherever you want them. All those counters are are divs or spans or lis that contain the numbers. So if you design the markup you want and style it the way you want, then you can drop the numbers into the containers with your script.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what 'users open tasks' refers to but to use jquery ,any other library and css you could create a  custom webpart for sharepoint or a sharepoint app with an apppart if using 2013, this allows you to leverage all CSS,HTML and any libraries you need with use of the sharepoint JSOM.

[Basic operations using JavaScript library code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx)